# apex:includescript disables my inline edit in VF page

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery_1_5_1}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.json2}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.cometd}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery_cometd}"/> 
</apex:form>
```

These codes disables my inline edit fields in VF page. Where should i put them, for me to be able to have inline edit fields again?

Please help.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I just found out that this one is the real one that disables my inline edit.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="pageLoad" action="{!doSummarize}" reRender="main" />
<apex:actionFunction name="display" action="{!dispSummary}" reRender="pbt, dispName, ownForecast1, ownForecast2, ownForecast3" />
```

that function will only work when the page loads

```
<script>
    window.onload = new function(){ pageLoad();}
</script>
```

and the javascript push notif

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Connect to the CometD endpoint
            $.cometd.init({
                    url: window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/cometd/26.0/',
                    requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}'}
                });
            // Subscribe to a topic. JSON-encoded update will be returned
            // in the callback
            $.cometd.subscribe('/topic/AllForecastDetailsSummary', function(message) {
                display();
            });
        });
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try putting all your script before apex:form tag like:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery_1_5_1}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.json2}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.cometd}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery_cometd}"/> 

    <apex:form>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: hello i've updated my question, can you have a look? thanks

Comment: Have you checked that when your page loads is there any error coming in browser console. And one more thing are you rerendering the panel which is inline?

Comment: hi @tandonprateek, i have this error in the browser console on page load: 
Appending message type to URI /cometd/26.0/ is not supported, disabling 'appendMessageTypeToURL' configuration

Comment: I think the problem is in making the URL. Rest looks fine. I have not used comentD.js so i cannot help you in depth.